# SmartGWT: Handling mouse down when a child element of Canvas is clicked

Tags: smartgwt

I have smartgwt Canvas to which a TextArea is added. I want to handle MouseDown event and change its border when user clicks anywhere on the canvas. My code looks like this.

```
final com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas can = new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas();
can.setCanFocus(true);
can.setBorder("2px Solid Blue");
can.setCanDragResize(true);
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
can.addChild(ta);
can.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {

                ChangeCanvasBorder(can);

            }
        });
```

MouseDown event is not fired when i click on TextArea contained in Canvas. Is there a way to handle click on canvas child elements?

I am new to gwt. I might have missed some configuration.

As an alternative i have tried the gwt's FocusPanel and i am able receive MouseDown when the TextArea added to FocusPanel is clicked.

I am using smartgwt 2.4 and gwt 2.4.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: If I'm right then TextArea is a GWT widget. Mixing SmartGWT and GWT widgets should be avoided wherever possible or you will get many headaches when trying to fix all the layout problems it creates. You should expect a lot of oddities and non-intuitive and non-obvious behavior when dealing with SmartGWT. SmartGWT is also very heavy and it will work slowly even on moderately good computers. Anyway, SmartGWT exposes TextAreaItem that you need to insert into a form widget.

Comment: @ZelwaPL, Thank you for quick reply. Agree with you, i changed my project to stick to SmartGWT widget as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ZalewaPL said, it is better to avoid mixing gwt and smartgwt widgets. I suggest you to use the TextAreaItem from smartgwt added to a DynamicForm. Here is a simple example:

```
final Canvas can = new Canvas();
can.setCanFocus(true);
can.setBorder("2px Solid Blue");
can.setCanDragResize(true);
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
TextAreaItem tai = new TextAreaItem("textarea");
form.setFields(tai);
can.addChild(form);
can.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
        changeCanvasBorder(can);
    }
});
```

But if you still want to use the TextArea widget from gwt, then you can do this:

```
abstract class CustomMouseDownHandler implements com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.MouseDownHandler, com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseDownHandler {
    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.MouseDownEvent event) {
        onMouseDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseDownEvent event) {
        onMouseDown();
    }

    public abstract void onMouseDown();
}

final Canvas can = new Canvas();
can.setCanFocus(true);
can.setBorder("2px Solid Blue");
can.setCanDragResize(true);
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
CustomMouseDownHandler mdh = new CustomMouseDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseDown() {
        changeCanvasBorder(can);
    }
};
ta.addMouseDownHandler(mdh);
can.addChild(ta);
can.addMouseDownHandler(mdh);
```

This one creates a new handler abstract class, which implements both MouseDownHandler interfaces and forwards their onMouseDown method to a new onMouseDown method. You have to create one implementation for this abstract class and use it for the Canvas and the TextArea widget too.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I choose the first suggestion. now able to hear the mousedown event.